# StackOverflowError when running Spring Batch job in Spring XD

Tags: spring-batch, spring-java-config, spring-xd

I have a Spring Batch job that is running through Spring XD. When I run it through my IDE everything runs fine, but when I run it through Spring XD I get the following error:

```
2015-07-21T12:05:51-0400 1.2.0.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-2 step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step loadPublicationRunStep in job MyLoader
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108) ~[gson-2.2.4.jar:na]
```

(the logs go on and on...)

Has anyone encountered something similar? Does anyone know what could be the potential cause?

Comment: Given that it's a Gson error, my bet is that it's data related (circular reference perhapse?).

Comment: When I run the exact same code through my IDE, however, I don't get that error...

Comment: Yes - the data is generated and then zipped. The job unzips and reads the .json files. Both the IDE and Spring XD jobs unzip the same files.... that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Are you packaging GSON up with your module?

Comment: I don't think so.... let me try to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, what version of XD are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring XD version 1.2.0, and also the gson jar was under the $XD_HOME/lib directory.

Comment: Possible version missmatch between your IDE and what comes with XD?